# How can I replace my calls to cvGetReal2D with cvmGet?

Tags: c++, windows, optimization, opencv

How can I replace my calls to `cvGetReal2D` with `cvmGet` ?

I have functions like

```
bool someFunction(CvPoint2D32f location, IplImage &image)
{
  // code
  z = cvGetReal2D(image, location.y, location.x);
  // code
}
```

I am trying to replace `cvGetReal2D` with `cvmGet` because I read that it is faster - but I am a very beginner in OpenCV (I am modifying code written by other people).

Will I have to create an entire `CvMat` every time, for every single point ? In that case, since I can't change the fact that I am passing an `IplImage`... the change will make the code slower, right ?

```
CvMat* imageCopy = cvCreateMat(image.width, image.height, image.depth);
```

(I have seen also constants like `CV_32FC1` - but I don't know how to choose)

Then, do I copy it ?

```
cvCopy(image, imageCopy);    // I hope this would copy the values
I tried - I get an exception...
```

Will it work on multi-channel matrix ? Do I have to ask how many channels, and iterate on them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert the IplImage to Mat using:

```
IplImage *img; 
Mat imgMat(img);
```

Then you can use `cvmGet`

`CV_32FC1` can be chosen like :

```
Mat imageCopy = cvCreateMat(image.width, image.height, image.depth, CV_32FC1);
```

I hope you are using OpenCV 2.4x

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

include these to use cv::Mat

to use cvarrtoMat:

```
IplImage A1; 
Mat B1 = cvarrToMat(&A1);
```

Comment: What is the use of Mat imgMat ? and... I have been trying to use it instead of CvMat just now, but I ran into an issue (in the header file, where I tried to pass it, I got the error 'cv' is not a class or namespace - didn't happen when I tried to use anything else from openCV) - still, if I make a Mat, would it not be better to use that ?

Comment: When I tried to use CvMat, I had no trouble creating it - see code above - but I got a Debug error trying to get data into it

Comment: The thing I am trying right now: cv::Mat imageCopy = cv::cvarrToMat( image, false ); - if I can get it past the compile errors from header file... Is this wrong ?

Comment: try: cv::Mat imageCopy = cv::cvarrToMat( &image, false )

Comment: Will try - I can't get cv::Mat to work in header file, so I may have to use CvMat after all, in which case I don't know how to put data into it... (I may not have to, it is passed as a boost shared pointer - will see as soon as I can get something to compile for cv::Mat)

Comment: Thank you. I was able to build - I found cv::Mat in core_c.h so I thought that was all I needed. Now though... On the cvarrToMat(&image, false) I get a Debug error: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001df2e8. I thought that this is not a copy, but a pointer to the data ? So I have pretty much what I had when I tried to copy data in the CvMat...

Comment: Thank you - I was just testing it - and I got it to work (since the IplImage was a pointer, I removed the &)... and one more thing... please... since you've been so helpful... on cv::Mat, I am no longer using cvmGet as I thought I was going to, but instead, B1.at<double>(y, x); and - of course it is crashing. I thought that this would be how to access Mat elements ? (x, y are the point coordinates, that I have checked are less than width/height respectively)

Comment: assuming B1 is grayscale: B1.at<uchar>(y, x). If B1 is CV_32F, B1.at<float>(y, x). you can accept my answer if it helped u in any way to make me happy ;)

Comment: Thank you sooooo much for your help, I run the program with a baseline and I got the same data, it really works !!!!